# comparision ValueStartingWithX%... like in sql but in a php comparision

Tags: php

Is it possible to do something similar to: `where like 'startingwith%'` like in SQL in a PHP if comparison ?
For example i want to display all values that **start with 123... but not the ones that start with 132...**

Tried :

```
if($x == 'aaa%')
```

but i'm pretty sure PHP handles a % like C as a modulo comparison.

I couldn't find if its possible to do such a thing in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that using [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) which returns the index of found substring:

```
if (strpos($x, 'ABC') === 0) {
    echo '$x starts with "ABC"';
}
```

But if you want to do it **case-insensitive** (as your SQL probably does), you can use [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php):

```
if (stripos($x, 'abc') === 0) {
    echo '$x starts with "ABC"';
}
```

If you want to get strings which **end** with a substring you could use [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php):

```
if (stripos($x, 'def') === (strlen($x) - strlen('def'))) {
    echo '$x ends with "def"';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `(.*)` as a wildcard.

Like:

```
if(preg_match("123(.*)", $var) === 1) 
{
    // do something
}
```

you need a loop around when you want to filter an array of course.

Additional reading for regex:

- [PHP preg_match](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php)
- [Tutorial about PHP regex](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html)

You can also use completely other approaches if you just want to check prefixes. There is a nice performance benchmark of solutions which can be found [here](http://maettig.com/code/php/php-performance-benchmarks.php#startswith).